# C# threading - lock or monitor needed?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to threading and i'm wondering if i have good code.
Situation: 3 classes, Reader, Writer and Data. Writer write data to Data as fast as he can, Reader, reads in every second (if writer didn't wrote new data he checks flag, if it's true, there are new data to read, if not he can use old ones).
Please tell me is it a valid code for Data class:

```
class GameData
{
    String GameData="";
    bool newData = false;
    public String ReadData()
    {
        newData = false;
        return GameData;
    }
    public void WriteData(String d)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            GameData = d;
            newData = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading [this free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Your description doesn't match the code. In the code, `readData` reads the data regardless of the value of `newData`. In fact, it doesn't look like `newData` accomplishes anything -- both `ReadData` and `WriteData` write it, but nobody reads it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - I assume the caller of ReadData() checks.

Comment: If you're writing faster than you're reading, then you're going to have to implement some sort of backing queue (or comparable mechanism) to hold pending reads, which, in turn, means you'll need to pull your Reads from the same queue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: At least as shown, that's not possible -- `newData` is local to the `GameData` class, so it's only visible to `ReadData` and `WriteData` (though this could be due to simplification for posting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reader Write Lock Slim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).[Blocking Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

A good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a [blocking collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). This will handle the locking for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only ensures that several writers will not write at the same time. It will not prevent ReadData from reading and changing the newData flag while a writer is writing and doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

2 consecutive writes overwrite the data. Is this intentional?
Are you checking newData from outside?
What behaviour are you trying to achieve/protect from ?